# How to setup flask+uWSGI app to timeout long requests

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I have a client and server setup (client is a product, can't be changed, server is what we coded, Python + Flask + uWSGI), where client sends HTTP requests at rapid pace with 10 sec timeout. After timeout is reached, client performs retry 3 more times, with same 10 sec timeout but some exponential back-off waiting.

Even though each individual task is processed rather quickly, because of the huge amount of requests being sent, tasks wait in uWSGI queue for more than 10 seconds and they time out in client. Problem is, even those timed out tasks will eventually be processed by server and when you include client retries, one task can be processed up to 4 times (1 original request + 3 retries).

Is there a way to setup my uWSGI server, so it timeouts all incoming requests that weren't processed within 10 second period?

I tried harakiri option of uWSGI, but it kills whole process and only when it's working for more than timeout. I also tried harakiri uWSGI decorator in python.
I tried literally every other timeout option in uWSGI docs and nothing worked as I needed.

You can replicate this problem using following code.

client.py

```
import requests
import threading

def foo():
    while True:
        try:
            resp = requests.get("http://localhost:9090/", timeout=5)
            print("I made it!", resp.text)
        except Exception as e:
            print("DIDN'T make it.. error:", e)

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=foo)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

server.py

```
import flask as fl
import time
import random

app = fl.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    t = random.randrange(1, 4)
    print("working for", str(t), "seconds...", end="")
    time.sleep(t)
    ident = random.randrange(1, 1000000)
    print("DONE WORKING, RETURNING RESULT!", "ID:", ident)
    return "I slept for " + str(t) + " seconds! ID: " + str(ident)
```

uwsgi.ini config file

```
[uwsgi]
http = :9090
wsgi-file = server.py
callable = app

master = true
processes = 2
strict = true
disable-logging = true

harakiri = 5
http-timeout = 4
```

Output from server looks like this:

```
working for  1  seconds...DONE WORKING, RETURNING RESULT!!! ID: 33021
working for  1  seconds...DONE WORKING, RETURNING RESULT!!! ID: 240084
working for  1  seconds...DONE WORKING, RETURNING RESULT!!! ID: 107112
working for  2  seconds...DONE WORKING, RETURNING RESULT!!! ID: 259223
working for  1  seconds...DONE WORKING, RETURNING RESULT!!! ID: 699282
working for  3  seconds...DONE WORKING, RETURNING RESULT!!! ID: 146855
working for  1  seconds...DONE WORKING, RETURNING RESULT!!! ID: 292973
working for  1  seconds...DONE WORKING, RETURNING RESULT!!! ID: 299534
```

And output from client throws disconnected errors, from http-timeout parameter, but server still processes the request:

```
I made it! I slept for 1 seconds! ID: 33021
I made it! I slept for 1 seconds! ID: 240084
I made it! I slept for 1 seconds! ID: 107112
I made it! I slept for 2 seconds! ID: 259223
DIDN'T make it.. error: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
I made it! I slept for 1 seconds! ID: 699282
I made it! I slept for 1 seconds! ID: 292973
I made it! I slept for 1 seconds! ID: 299534
I made it! I slept for 1 seconds! ID: 249919
DIDN'T make it.. error: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
I made it! I slept for 2 seconds! ID: 608657
DIDN'T make it.. error: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not much docs on the uWSGI side but, would checking if the connection (request from the client) is still "open" work?

see https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonModule.html#uwsgi.is_connected

something like:

```py
if uwsgi.is_connected(uwsgi.connection_fd())
    <process request>
```

Comment: unfortunately, this didnt work. i even tried by increasing server "processing time" to 8 seconds, so every request from client times out but no luck